# $P(X \geq c) \leq e^{-ct +\frac{t^2}{2}}$ , where $X \sim N(0,1)$

Tags: probability, statistics, measure-theory, inequality

Prove that:

$$P(X \geq c) \leq e^{-ct +\frac{t^2}{2}},$$ where $X \sim N(0,1)$ and $c>0$, $t \in\mathbb R$.

The problem should be solved easily by using the equality:

$$P(X \geq c) = P(e^{Xt} \geq e^{ct})$$

And by using the Markov inequality thereafter.

But I have a doubt that since $t\in\mathbb R$, so when $t<0$, how do I prove the above result?

Comment: When $t<0$ the RHS is $>1$ hence there is nothing to prove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To consolidate your observation for $t\geqslant0$ and @Did's comment for $t<0$:

If $t=0$ then $e^{-ct + \frac{t^2}2}=1$ so the inequality is trivial.

If $t<0$, then $-ct+\frac{t^2}2>0$ so $e^{-ct+\frac{t^2}2}>1$ and again the inequality is trivial.

If $t>0$, then $x\mapsto e^{xt}$ is monotone increasing, so $X\geqslant c$ iff $e^{Xt}\geqslant e^{ct}$, and $\mathbb P(X\geqslant c) = \mathbb P(e^{Xt} \geqslant e^{ct})$. By Markov's inequality,

$$\mathbb P(e^{Xt}\geqslant e^{ct})\leqslant \frac{\mathbb E[e^{Xt}]}{e^{ct}} = e^{-ct +\frac{t^2}2},$$
as desired.